# Classic ASP, IIS 8.5, CINT CLNG not working

Tags: asp-classic, windows-8.1, iis-8

Reinstalled my dev machine with win 8.1
Enabled ASP, installed my legacy websites that I have to maintain, installed sites as an application in IIS, enabled parent paths, send errors to browser on, full detail set on in error pages. All is working well, except when I work with numbers

I'm working in a system that captures financial data inputted by users, so often a number will be: 100.0 or 
100.000 or 
100 or 
100,00

so I have a function that (I've used on loads of websites in the past) that will standardise the irregularities into a constant format, such as 100.00 (ie: proper decimal, always using a dot, etc)

This line now fails on win 8.1 IIS 8.5: ***If Cdbl(myString) = Cdbl(0) Then***

```
Function ProperDecimal(s_String)
    Dim CharPlace, DotChar, iLoop, strCurrentChar, myString
    myString = TRIM(s_String)
    If ISNULL(myString) OR myString = "" Then myString = 0
    myString = REPLACE(myString,",",".")

    'Find where the comma or dot is, ie: 100.00 is in position 3 (from the right)
    CharPlace = 1
    DotChar = 0
    For iLoop = Len(Replace(myString, " ", "")) to 1 Step -1
        strCurrentChar = mid(Replace(myString, " ", ""), iLoop, 1)
        If strCurrentChar = "." OR strCurrentChar = "," Then
            DotChar = CharPlace
            Exit For
        End If
    CharPlace = CharPlace + 1
    Next

    'If string is zero, leave it at zero, we dont need 0.00
    If Cdbl(myString) = Cdbl(0) Then
        'ignore it, no decimal places needed
        ProperDecimal = myString
    Else
        'Where is the DOT
        Select Case DotChar
            Case 0 'eg: 100 will be converted to 100.00
                ProperDecimal = (myString & ".00")
            Case 1 'eg: 100. will be converted to 100.00
                ProperDecimal = (myString & "00")
            Case 2 'eg: 100.0 will be converted to 100.00
                ProperDecimal = (myString & "0")
            Case 3 'eg: 100.00 will remain
                ProperDecimal = (myString)
            Case Else '(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, etc) 'eg: 100.001
                ProperDecimal = ProperDecimal(Round(myString,2))
        End Select
    End If
End Function

Call ProperDecimal("112.05")
```

This lead me to try other methods other than CDbl

```
Response.write(isNumeric(s_String)) 'works, returns false because this is a string
Response.write(CINT(myString))
Response.write(CLNG(myString))
Response.write(CDBL(myString))
```

Returns this:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
Type mismatch: 'CINT'

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
Type mismatch: 'CLNG'

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
Type mismatch: 'CDBL'

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
Type mismatch: 'CINT'

If I then change the If statement to convert the 0 to a string, it works:

```
If myString = CSTR(0) Then
```

But I really dont want to be comparing strings to strings especially with numbers

This is now the second project this is happening on. The previous project I had to change the decimal comma to a fullstop (112,05 had to be 112.05) so I thought it had something to do with regional settings and the comma being listed as decimal character. But am getting different results now, its driving me up the wall.. plz assist if you can. Ta

Comment: Show us the code of your isNumber() function. that's not a vbscript function is it?

Comment: Its standard classic asp/VB as far as I know http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_isnumeric.asp

Comment: IsNumeric != IsNumber

Comment: ok, IsNumeric returns false, that would be because its a string.. strings aren't the problem, numbers are, I think my ASP is broken, the built in methods dont seem to work, not all of them, just some of them - maybe MS didnt port over ASP to iis 8 properly or something I dunno

Comment: An integer is a whole number, have you tried Cdec (for a decimal)?

Comment: MsgBox and Cdec are not available in ASP. This also fails: FormatNumber(s_String) shows Type mismatch: 'FormatNumber'. Same for CCur(s_String). Why cant I cast a string to anything else?

Comment: Show us the code where you have a Problem. not any other code where you try to reproduce your error. the code you hav definitley does not work because of the use of isNumber

Comment: I just tried <%= Cint("1.5") %> on IIS7 and it rounded up to 2.  <%= Ccur("1.5") %> gave me 1.5.  You're right about Cdec

Comment: @ulluoink I've updated the post to reflect my original code. This works in IIS 7, it does not work in IIS 8.5

Comment: @Mark ok thanks. sorry man i tried that on my win 8.1 machine and it all works. you definitely have another Problem then os/iis version

Comment: Any Progress? I would like a Function which try CInt/CDbl and if it breaks, replace the periods with commas and try again. If that also fails, return 0 or 0.00 which ever the case may be

Comment: This has everything to do with LCID/Regional Settings. But it is only in windows 8 which this differs. I have played around and the only thing I can think of is to create your own cInt cDbl functions. Find and replace `CInt(` with `castInt(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CInt on the server works fine (2008 R2), on the clients pc (windows Xp and windows 7) but on my windows 8 machine, this is an issue.

I made my own two functions which I use now instead of CInt and CDbl. You can make more if needed. Pretty simple and tested,

## **EDIT:**

Changed the function names toe shorter versions. Easier to replace and to use. Also does not clash with Javascripts parseInt if you do a search

```
Function pInt(Str)
    Dim val : val = 0

    '==Test Comma=='
    On Error Resume Next
        val = CInt(Replace(Str, ".", ","))

    '==Test Period=='
    On Error Resume Next
        val = CInt(Replace(Str, ",", "."))

    On Error Goto 0
    pInt = val
End Function

Function pDbl(Str)
    Dim val : val = 0

    '==Test Comma=='
    On Error Resume Next
        val = CDbl(Replace(Str, ".", ","))

    '==Test Period=='
    On Error Resume Next
        val = CDbl(Replace(Str, ",", "."))

    On Error Goto 0
    pDbl = val
End Function
```

I am not a pro in ClassicASP/VBScript but this works. I like my C# ASP.net